# Linking together a "chain" in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a file object with following properties C#

```
File {
    Source;
    Target;
}
```

I have a list of Files which looks like this:

```
File[0]- Source :B :Target :C
File[1]- Source :A :Target :B
File[2]- Source :AA :Target :E
File[3]- Source :F :Target :G
File[4]- Source :G :Target :H
File[5]- Source :E :Target :F
File[6]- Source :C :Target :AA
```

How can I sort it so that the source of the next item is equal to the target of the previous item?

```
File[0]- Source :A :Target :B
File[1]- Source :B :Target :C
File[2]- Source :C :Target :AA
File[3]- Source :AA :Target :E
File[4]- Source :E :Target :F
File[5]- Source :F :Target :G
File[6]- Source :G :Target :H
```

A,B....H given in source are just examples. It would be actual file names including the file path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a list of files:

```
List<File> files;
```

Simply do:

```
var sorted = files.OrderBy(f => f.Source).ToList();
```

---

In response to the edited question, here is one possible way of doing it. Let's define a generic method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Chain<T, S> (
    IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, S> sourceSelector, Func<T, S> targetSelector, T seed) {
    var dict = list.ToDictionary(sourceSelector, x => x);
    var curr = seed; 

    do {
        yield return curr; 
    } while(dict.TryGetValue(targetSelector(curr), out curr));
}
```

I use a dictionary here for speed with large lists since dictionary lookups are O(1). However, one may just as easily use a simple linear search with an amortized lookup time of O(n), but with less overhead for small-sized lists.

One may use this method as follows:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int, int>> {
    Tuple.Create(1, 2),
    Tuple.Create(3, 5),
    Tuple.Create(2, 3),
    Tuple.Create(8, 13),
    Tuple.Create(5, 8),
};

var chained = Chain<Tuple<int, int>, int>(list,
    x => x.Item1,
    x => x.Item2,
    list.First());

foreach (var i in chained)
    Console.Write(i);
```

This prints out:

```
(1, 2)(2, 3)(3, 5)(5, 8)(8, 13)
```

In your case, you may write:

```
var chained = Chain<File, string>(files,
    f => f.Source,
    f => f.Target,
    files.OrderBy(f => f.Source).First());
```

...assuming of course that `Source` and `Target` are of type `string`.

Comment: wow. it works.but wondering how it is. even if I give f.A or f.B or anything as source it works. can you please explain how this works even without using the target

Comment: sorry I was wrong .. this will not work. this sorts only on the key.. what is source has something like A or  f:\AA.txt or 2 anything like that.  I want the full list to be sorted based on the pattern I mentioned .. First one in the list would be the entry whose source would not be a target of anything.. Hence there in the list "A" comes because "A" is not a target of anything. If we follow that pattern, it would be A - B, then B - C, because source B is present in the A- B where B is target

Comment: Can you edit your question to include an example of your desired behavior where my answer fails?

Comment: I added the changes. if the file name has A or AA as source in the example , then what you told will fail.

Comment: I hope this suits your needs. I use a dictionary here for speed with large lists since dictionary lookups are O(1). However, one may just as easily use a simple linear search with an amortized lookup time of O(n).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that response. will check that out

Comment: It worked . What I understood is that if we provide the seed it will fetch the sequence. Is there any way from a list it can automatically form this pattern without providing any seed. What I mean is that, in the Tuple list you have give list.First(). That means starting from (1,2). can this autopopulate the same sequence without providing any seed. It should stop the sequence with (1,2) in the top because no other tuple has (X,1).

Comment: Indeed, the seed determines the starting point. More generally, you can use `seed = list.OrderBy(f => f.Source).First()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132576/discussion-between-user3689864-and-mateen-ulhaq).